# How can I use javascript to solve this equation?

Tags: javascript, math

```
P := 1/(1+10^((Y-X)/400))
M*(1-P) = Result
```

Please help how would I go about calculating that in java script, I am not sure I believe all the brackets confuse the program. I already have a script determining x and y via user input just unable to get the script to correctly calculate the above math.

Comment: Where's `M` coming from?

Comment: @100 Nightcore It would be helpful if you could post what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Math.pow` for exponentiation, `^` is a character reserved for bitwise XOR.

```
var Y = 1;
var X = 2;
var M = 3;

var P = 1 / (1 + Math.pow(10, ((Y - X) / 400)));
var Result = M * (1 - P);
```